# htaccess redirect folder to a third level domain

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

I have a website `https://www.mywebsite.it` with a few pages in the root.

Then I have a folder named `myapp` where I have an application developed. 
Actually the application myapp can be accessed via:

```
https://www.mywebsite.it/myapp
https://myapp.mywebsite.it
```

What I want to do is: if the user navigates to https://www.mywebsite.it/myapp apache will redirect him to https://myapp.mywebsite.it

Is something like:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/?myapp/ https://myapp.mywebsite.it/? [R=301,L]
```

inside the vhost configuration file going to work?

Comment: Have you tried out your solution?

Comment: It is a production environment. I cannot do shots in the dark with that and I don't have a sandbox to test...

Comment: do not use .htaccess if you have access the to main configuration. .htaccess is not a rewrites depot, it is meant for users without admin rights to the HTTPD server. I would recommend you to define a virtualhost for each hostname name and have a simple `Redirect /myapp/ https://myapp.mydomain.it/` in the one you want to redirect to the other. Using mod_rewrite for this is excessive.

Comment: Thanks @ezra-s but if you read the question I already have a vhost for the domain and the question was how to update the configuration file of this vhost. Anyway I prefer htacces approach since I consider it cleaner and lighter

Comment: Thanks for the clarification on your question. About .htaccess again, it is not lighter, nor cleaner. It complicates rewrites such as it is per-dir context and produces much extra overhead in the server, for each hit the .htaccess gets read at least 3 times. In any case, good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside `myapp/.htaccess` you can use this rule:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(mydomain\.it)$ [NC]
RewriteRule .* http://myapp.%1/$0 [L,R=301,NE]
```